# Adding classes/IDs at different points in a page

Tags: javascript, css, function

***To avoid confusion and before you read on, this is NOT "how many pixels down" but at, for example, `<section id="smaller">` then it would add a class. I'm new to javascript so please take that with a grain of salt. Thanks.***

I'm trying to change the header by adding a new attribute class to the header file. Following code works ok on desktop when your width never changes but what if your on a phone and your design is responsive? Yes, this is exactly why I need your help. I tried so many thing already and don't know how to get this setup like I want. I am new to web dev and this is one of my first few websites.

My code right now:

```
function init() {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', function (e) {
        var distanceY = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop, header = document.querySelector("header");
        if (distanceY > 606) {
            header.setAttribute("class", "smaller");
        } else {
            header.removeAttribute("class");
        }
    });
 }
window.onload = init();
```

Couple of things I need to clear up, and/or if you're a little confused:

- the header is the actual `<header>` not a div with a header class or id.
- like I said, this does work right now but is only useful for a fixed width for every screen size
- I'm including this code on a js file which is linked just before the ending of the `<body>` tag.
- "606" being the length down the page in pixels when the change happens

Is there a way to add an attribute to the header when you reach a certain place on the web page? If anyway could give me some guidance, that would be great. Thanks a bunch for reading this and enjoy the rest of your day. :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `element.getBoundingClientRect()` to retrieve screen position information of your object. This will give you an object containing bottom, height, left, etc., for your task you might want to use `top` and `height`. In combination with `window.innerHeight` you can code what you want.

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
    var r = header.getBoundingClientRect();
    if (r.top < 300)
        header.setAttribute("class", "smaller");
    else
        header.removeAttribute("class");
});
```

However, there are probably better ways to do this, have a look at "css media queries", they offer almost anything you might require to make your pages responsive.

Comment: Would it be too much to ask for an implementation? :P Sorry, kinda overwhelmed right now. It would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: i added some example implementation, i dont know exactly what you are going for, but this code adds a class to an element that was going above 300px on the screen. TIP: have a look at jQuery when you are new to JS, it will help a lot with doing things elegantly.

Comment: The other answer posted by @caramba helped me with the explaining my goal = if you first check where a element is on a page and set that to `distanceY`, they you can still use the rest of the code. This is a way of doing it however it should help you understand... hopefully. Thanks for your answer, I'll look into it and try it out.

Comment: I've added a working solution to the post. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out a way to do it with `.position();`. Here's my explanation:

`#sub-services` is the element I want to get the position of.

`el` is the position of the `#sub-services`.

And `smaller` is a class added to the `<header>`.

---

Here's the full code which I'm using in my site:

```
var el = $( "#sub-services" );
var position = el.position();

function init() {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', function (e) {
        var distanceY = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop, header = document.querySelector("header");
        if (distanceY > position.top) {
            header.setAttribute("class", "smaller");
        } else {
            header.removeAttribute("class");
        }
    });
}
window.onload = init();
```

It is much easier to do it with jquery. Thanks to @caramba for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks a bunch for everything. 

Comment: It's that your comment was helpful, not the "CSS media queries". Honestly not trying to be hateful. And I can't upvote comments. :/ +I have to wait 2 days to get my answer accepted.